# How to pass a string containing quotes as an `include` parameter in Liquid/Jekyll?

Tags: yaml, jekyll, liquid

Consider: I want to pass a block of text as a parameter in an `include` tag. The block of text contains a quote. For example:

```
Breaking news:

Area man says, "This is newsworthy!"
```

There are several ways I can think of to do this:

## 1. Wrap in single quotes

```
{%
    include newsitem.html
    content='Breaking news:

Area man says, "This is newsworthy!"'
%}
```

This is not ideal since there may be single quotes/apostrophes in the text block.

## 2. Use `captures`

```
{% capture newscontent %}
Breaking news:

Area man says, "This is newsworthy!"
{% endcapture %}
{%
    include newsitem.html
    content=newscontent
%}
```

This is not ideal because it is verbose.

## 3. Escape quotes

```
{%
    include newsitem.html
    content="Breaking news:

Area man says, \"This is newsworthy!\""
%}
```

This is not ideal because if there are many quotes then they will all need backslashes, which will be tiresome to add.

## 4. Use `captures` and `include`

```
{% capture content %}{% include_relative newscontent.md %}{% endcapture %}
{%
    include newsitem.html
    content=content
%}
```

This is not really ideal because it is also fairly verbose.

## 5. Use frontmatter and/or YAML

```
---
newscontent: |
  Breaking news:

  Area man says, "This is newsworthy!"
---

{%
    include newsitem.html
    content=page.newscontent
%}
```

This is not ideal because it spreads out page content in a weird way.

---

Now, I absolutely admit these are all really trivial complaints. But mostly in order to gain a better familiarity with Jekyll/liquid, I'd like to know if there's another way to pass multi-line parameters containing quotes to `include`. What would be **GREAT** is if I could use backtics, or some other character that isn't very common in textual content:

```
{%
    include newsitem.html
    content=`Breaking news:

Area man says, "This is newsworthy!"`
%}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be supported. What are your thoughts? Thanks!